# Куда скинуть tcl файлы для тем tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Нашел несколько файлов с темами для Tkinter, но никак не могу их установить. И в папку с ttk к  темам бросал, и устанавливал ttkhemes через pip и туда кидал, ничего не помогает.

---

### UPD

Определил что проблема в том, что тема не может найти файлы png(она на них построенна).